# Calculate an integral (Complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega\supset\overline{D}(0,1)$ an open set, let $f,g:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic functions. Suppose that $f$ does't have zeros in $\partial D(0,1)$. Calculate:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z) dz$$

**My attempt:**

I want to show that the integral is $0$. As $g$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$, is continuous in $\Omega$, in particuar in $\partial D(0,1)$ wich is compact. So, $g$ reaches its maximum in $\partial D(0,1)$. Then, there exists $M\geq0$ such that $|g(z)|\leq M \ \forall z\in \partial D(0,1)$. Then, we have:
$$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z) dz\right|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\left|\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z)\right| dz\leq\frac{M}{2\pi }\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\left|\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right| dz$$

I would like to apply the Argument Principle, as we have something similiar, but I don't know how to do it. In fact, I don't know if this is going to help me, because I know f has no poles in $D(0,1)$, but I don't know anything about its zeros. Please, guide me.

Comment: Your inequalities cannot give the exact value of the integral, can they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: $f$ has at most finitely many zeros inside the contour and $\frac {f'(z)} {f(z)}$ has simple poles at those points. The residue of $\frac {f'(z)g(z)} {f(z)}$ at a zero $z_0$ of $f$ is $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) \frac {f'(z)g(z)} {f(z)} =g(z_0)$ by the definition of $f'(z_0)$. Hence the given integral equals the sum of the values of $g$ at the zeros of $f$.

Comment: Thanks! Why $f$ has at most finitely zeros? Because if it has infitintely of them, by the identity theorem would be constatly zero and that contradicts the hypothesis?

Comment: Yes. It is crucial that $f$ is holomorhic in a region that includes the closed unit disk. By compactness of this disk any infinite set in it would have  a limit point and this allows us to use the identity theorem. @GoRza